# Xamain.IOS.GoogleSignIn library error

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.ios, google-signin

In the ios project we have installed firebase ios binding libraries, also we need GoogleSignIn library, but after installing it we have some errors in build time.

```
Error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) (GoBatumi.IOS)


error MT5209: Error: file not found: /Users/tornike/Desktop/gobatumimobile/GoBatumi.IOS/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/GoogleSignIn (GoBatumi.IOS) Native linking

MTOUCH: Error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log. (MT5202)
```

I think Xamarin.Firebase packages and google packages have some dependency on each other, and I think it has some version problems so.

```
Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Analytics version - 4.0.5.1
Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Auth version - 4.4.1.1
Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core version - 4.0.13.1
Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.InstanceID version - 2.0.8
Xamarin.Google.iOS.SignIn version - 4.1.1.1
```

Is there some way to solve this problem?
What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

1) Clean the solution

2) Delete obj and bin folder

3) Add **--registrar:static** as Additional mtouch argument

If this doesnt solve the problem, make sure to use the last version of XCode

Comment: When I add -registrar:static argument, it occurs 11 error, "Can't find Firebase.IOS.Core" and same on all firebase libraries. But I've installed them and have in packages.conf already